# Python Telebot - Поочерёдный вызов функции

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

**Такая ситуация:** бот принимает ссылку на сайт (по ТЗ надо), после этого он должен попросить у пользователя номер статьи.
**Проблема:** как сделать так, чтобы вторая, уточняющая, функция "молчала" и ждала, пока не сработает первая/пока её не позовёт первая функция? Чувствую, что нужен какой-то callback, но пока даже не знаю, куда копать.
**Что нарыл:** в документации есть хендлер `@bot.callback_query_handler`, но почему-то не работает: `Parameter func unfilled`.
Если хендлер подобран правильно, то какой `func` мне необходимо указать?
Код прилагаю:

```
# Основная логика работы бота
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text[8:15] == "articles":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Прекрасно! Я принял Вашу ссылку и принимаюсь за работу.")
        clarify_the_ticket(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду. Попробуйте использовать /help.")


# Уточнение номера статьи
@bot.callback_query_handler(content_types=['text'])
def clarify_the_ticket(message):
    global id_of_the_ticket
    try:
        if int(message.text):
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Хорошо, спасибо. Продолжаю работать. ")
            id_of_the_ticket = int(message.text) - 1
            main()
            return id_of_the_ticket
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Необходимо было ввести число. Попробуйте снова.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение таково: вторая функция ждёт, пока пользователь не введёт сообщение.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    global pause
    if message.text[8:21] == "travel.yandex" and not pause:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Прекрасно! Я принял Вашу ссылку, осталось только уточнить номер билета (сверху вниз). Если билет один, то отправьте число 1.")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, clarify_the_ticket)  # Ожидаю, пока пользователь введёт сообщение с числом, потом вызывается функция clarify...
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Прошу прощения, но я не понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду. Попробуйте использовать /help.")
```

Решил через `bot.register_next_step_handler(message, clarify_the_ticket)`